# Referencing a variable using a string of the same name in Java?

Tags: javascript, string, reference

In Java, let's say I have...

```
let hello = 10;
```

Is it possible to retrieve hello's value (10) using the string reference 'hello'?
Something like valueOf(....'hello'....) = 10

Comment: It is very unlikely that you have a class called `let` (which does not conform to the Java naming conventions) that can be assigned an integer. Is your question about [tag:javascript]?

Comment: This may not be a duplicate. It may be a misunderstanding as pointed out by @JohannesKuhn.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, it is Javascript / Google Script. What I need to do is use the string 'hello' to return the variable of the same name, surely this possible?

Answer (score -2):

This is how you can retrive in Java. Also let is used in JavaScript not in Java.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = "10";
        int helloNum = Integer.valueOf(hello); //converting String "10" into int 10
        
        
        int num = 10;
        String numString = String.valueOf(num);//converting int 10 to string "10"
        
    }
}
```

Comment: From my understanding this answer does not match the question. It's about dynamically accessing some variable by a given string, not about parsing the string.

Comment: @berse2212 is spot on

Comment: I've just found the answer, by using eval('hello') to get to the hello variable.

Comment: @user1488934 `eval` does not exist in Java. Was your question about [tag:javascript] all along?